# Get User Selected Range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

How can I get a range of cells selected via user mouse input for further processing using VBA?

Comment: Record a macro, perform your actions, stop macro and then see the generated code.

Comment: Tried that but that generates a predefined range.  I want a to get a range that will vary every time.

Comment: That is because you have "Use Relative References" disabled (it's in the Developer tab in the Code group).  As below answer refers to, it's the Selection object (which is a Range instance) that will get recorded.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can loop through the Selection object to see what was selected.  Here is a code snippet from Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa203726(office.11).aspx):

```
Sub Count_Selection()
    Dim cell As Object
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0
    For Each cell In Selection
        count = count + 1
    Next cell
    MsgBox count & " item(s) selected"
End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't Selection.Count suffice? I think the Count property is available on Selection object. Looping through the entire selection seems an overhead.

Comment: He was just posting an exampel on how to use the selection object.  I use the count property in my code

Comment: still depends on what you are trying to do with the selection. I'm not sure it is entirely reliable if you were say deleting cells from a range during enumeration. Although that is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: How can I count only the visible rows?

Comment: Instead of `Dim cell As Object` it's better to use `Dim cell As Range`

Answer (score 60):

`Selection` is its own object within VBA.  It functions much like a `Range` object.

Selection and Range do not share all the same properties and methods, though, so for ease of use it might make sense just to create a range and set it equal to the Selection, then you can deal with it programmatically like any other range.

```
Dim myRange as Range
Set myRange = Selection
```

For further reading, check out the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223084(office.11).aspx).

Comment: While selection is of type Range, what props & methods is it missing? I always cast it straight to Range type anyways but just interested.

Answer (score 23):

This depends on what you mean by "get the range of selection". If you mean getting the range **address** (like "A1:B1") then use the Address property of Selection object - as Michael stated Selection object is much like a Range object, so most properties and methods works on it.

```vba
Sub test()
    Dim myString As String
    myString = Selection.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: I prefer .Address(0, 0) as this returns the address without the $ symbols. This is preferable when working in vba.

Answer (score 0):

I found what seems to me to be an easier or simpler way:

```
xx = Selection.Address
```

I know I'm registered, but I don't remember and do not have handy my password.  So I used another email address.