# How to refer to a selected block of cells in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

How to refer in the code to the selected range of cells in the active sheet.
To clarify, I am not asking how to select a range of cell.

Is there any ActiveRange ActiveRegion or something?
I haven't found it...

For example, (not working) here is a simple sub:

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim region, cel As Range
    
    region = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
    For Each cel In region
        cel = 1
    Next cel
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean `Selection.Address` ?

Comment: this might be of more help than my previous comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875415/loop-through-each-cell-in-a-range-of-cells-when-given-a-range-object

Comment: There are some more answers in this thread that may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080741/get-user-selected-range

Answer (score 0):

A couple of remarks:
Define all the variables types and Selection is already a Range if a Range is selected. Beware that it may return other objects, so you should check the type of object returned before working with it

[Read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.selection)

```
Public Sub LoopActiveRange()

    Dim sourceCell As Range

    For Each sourceCell In Selection
        sourceCell = 1
    Next sourceCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

*To work with Selected cells use [Selection property (Excel) MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Selection)*

***Example***

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim rng As Range
    
    For Each rng In Selection
        DoEvents
        rng.Value = "value"  ' adds a to all selected cells
    Next

End Sub
```

---

> **Remarks** 
> *<sub>The returned object type depends on the current selection (for example, if a cell is selected, this property returns a Range object). The Selection property returns Nothing if nothing is selected.</sub>*